# Converting date4j DateTime to Calendar or Date

Tags: android, datetime, calendar

i am trying to convert a DateTime from date4j library to a Calendar instance or a Date instance, any works. Currently the code i have to convert it to a Calendar instance is this

```
    Calendar Qurancal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Qurancal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dateTime.getWeekDay());
    Qurancal.set(Calendar.YEAR, dateTime.getYear());
    Qurancal.set(Calendar.MONTH, dateTime.getMonth());
    Qurancal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, dateTime.getDayOfYear());
    Qurancal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dateTime.getStartOfDay().getDay());
    Qurancal.set(Calendar.HOUR, dateTime.getHour());
    Qurancal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, dateTime.getMinute());
    Qurancal.set(Calendar.SECOND, dateTime.getSecond());
```

but this isnt working perfectly, as currently all the dates show a differ of 1 or 2 days

Answer (score 0):

fixed

removing this line from the above code fixed everything

```
 Qurancal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dateTime.getStartOfDay().getDay());
```